# Should we flag old questions / answers?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

Yesterday I flagged an old answer. I tend to check every post I read, even ancient ones, whether they are okay for SO.

So when doing some research, I stumbled on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583815/login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-network-service/2583935#2583935).

The outline is something like this (for future reference):

> try to take a look at the following links.
>
> [LINK TO SO ANSWER 1]
>
> [LINK TO SO ANSWER 2]
>
> [LINK TO SO ANSWER 3]

This were all links to existing answers on SO, so they even aren't useful for future reference.

According to the official policy of SE ([Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)) this is clearly 'not an answer'. So I flagged the question.

As you can guess, the flag was declined:

> a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Why was this flag declined? Is it because

- it is an old question;
- has a few upvotes;
- was accepted;
- any other reason?

Comment: I think it would be because it was accepted and it is old.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It matches very good 'link-only answer' delete reason with **Low Quality Queue.** It is also very likely to be deleted once it gets there.

However, it needs 4 downvotes until it could be flagged as 'low quality'. Other flags are handled by moderators, which are usually more restrained to take any action, since their votes are binding.

Comment: Okay, so the only is to gather downvotes? It has two already...

Comment: Also, why would a mod be more restrained than the community? I think it should be the other way around.

Comment: I can't speak for mods, but in normal review queue, if you think you're 90% right, you do the action, because even if you're wrong, than others will do correct action. The mod that does action when he's 90% confident is making 10% mistakes which will be yelled on meta - quite a lot.

Comment: But mods should know the rules the best...

Comment: From my experiece, answers like that are more likely to be deleted when handled by community (VLQ) than when handled by mods, but my experience may not be representative.